# How to join the two variables like table format in linux?

Tags: bash, posix

How to join the two variables or more variables like columns of a table?

I have `var1`, `var2`

```
echo $var1

10
50
30
20
40
```

then

```
echo $var2

111
222
333
444
555
```

then I want the output like

```
10   111
50   222
30   333
20   444
40   555
```

after I combine the two variables.

Answer (score 5):

With `paste` and `bash`'s Process Substitution:

```
paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2")
```

Output:

```
10      111
50      222
30      333
20      444
40      555
```

Answer (score 4):

With the `pr` tool, assuming your shell is bash

```sh
printf "%s\n%s\n" "$var1" "$var2" | pr -2 -T -s$'\t'
```

Or

```sh
pr -2T -s$'\t' <<END
$var1
$var2
END
```

---

Or, a while-read loop:

```sh
while IFS= read -r a <&3; IFS= read -r b <&4; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$a" "$b"; done 3<<<"$var1" 4<<<"$var2"
```

or more nicely laid-out

```sh
while
    IFS= read -r a <&3
    IFS= read -r b <&4
do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$a" "$b"
done 3<<<"$var1" \
     4<<<"$var2"
```